# Ipc global variable and pipes

Tags: c, ipc

Lets say I have a process with n children,and I want to keep count of a certain condition that may verify itself in those children(once per child,after that child exits),at a certain count though children need to exit.
If I wanted to do it by pipe, how should I proceed ?

So far I have in mind two ways :

- Using two pipes(read from pipe1,write to father on pipe2,read from pipe1,update count,write on pipe1)
- Creating n pipes the ith child would read the ith pipe to check the count and then terminate or update count on all the others pipes

Could you please tell me if one of those approaches are legit,if not maybe explain why ?

Comment: Can't follow your line of thought. Please rephrase the question.

Comment: A condition may verify itself true in one or more of children, all the other children must know how many times did that condition become true in their brothers so they know what to do(exit or continue), I was asking how to do it with pipes